# Induction proof: $\sum_{k=1}^n k^32^k \leq n^32^{n+1}$

Tags: induction

Having trouble solving the induction proof for:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^32^k \leq n^32^{n+1}$$

EDIT: supposed to be $k^32^k$

Comment: Why induction? Rather use $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^32^k\leqslant\sum_{k=1}^n n^32^k=n^3\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k=n^3(2^{n+1}-2)\leqslant n^32^{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^3 2^k = \sum_{k=1}^nk^32^k + (n+1)^3 2^{n+1} \leq n^32^{n+1} + (n+1)^3 2^{n+1} = \dots$$

Answer (score 0):

For $n=1$ the claim is clear.

Suppose $\sum_{k=1}^nk^22^k\leq n^32^{n+1}$. Now

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}k^22^k&=\sum_{k=1}^nk^22^k+(n+1)^22^{n+1}\\&\leq n^32^{n+1}+(n+1)^22^{n+1}\\
&=(n^3+(n+1)^2)2^{n+1}\\
&=(n^3+n^2+2n+1)2^{n+1}\\
&\leq(n^3+3n^2+3n+1)2^{n+2}\\
&=(n+1)^32^{(n+1)+1}
\end{align}

And the proof is complete.